# lazy implicit val not found

Tags: scala, implicit

Why can't scala find the implicit here?

```
class A

class Foo {
  lazy val x = implicitly[A]
  implicit lazy val a = new A
}
```

> error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: A

But this works just fine:

```
class Foo {
  lazy val x = implicitly[A]
  implicit lazy val a: A = new A // note explicit result type
}
```

> defined class Foo

FWIW I'm stuck on Scala 2.10 for this application. Also, replacing `lazy val` with `def` doesn't seem to change anything.

In my actual application, I've got a file with a bunch of implicits defined for various domain objects, some of which depend on each other. It seems like a nightmare to try and arrange them in a way that makes sure all dependencies come before their respective dependents, so I marked them all as `lazy`. Having to explicitly declare the type of each of these vals muddies up the code, and seems like it should be unnecessary. Any way around this?

Comment: This happens with Scala2.11 too. As you said,  correct order does work `implicit lazy val a = new A; lazy val x = implicitly[A]`. Shouldn't this be a bug in Scala ?

Comment: If you move the implicitly call to be after the implicit lazy val definition it compiles without needing to add the type annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't scala find the implicit here?
>
> > [I have implemented a slightly more permissive rule: An implicit conversion without explicit result type is visible only in the text following its own definition. That way, we avoid the cyclic reference errors. I close for now, to see how this works. If we still have issues we migth come back to this.](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-801?focusedCommentId=41419&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-41419)
>
> Having to explicitly declare the type of each of these vals muddies up the code, and seems like it should be unnecessary.

For implicits specifically, I recommend doing so nonetheless. This issue isn't the only reason; if in the future type of an implicit changes unintentionally, this can break compilation in hard-to-understand ways. See also the issue linked above:

> > Martin wrote on the scala-user list, "In general it's a good idea always to write a result type for an implicit method. Maybe the language should require it."
> >
> > I've been bitten myself a couple times by problems that went away once I added a result type to an implicit so I thought I'd open a ticket on this.